# Convert a Base-16 String to Base-32 in Android

Tags: java, android, base32

I want to convert a base16 string to base32 String. For example, if i have a base-16 String -- "000000000288" now i want to convert it to it base-32 counterpart ("K-8").

There is a website which does it:

http://www.unitconversion.org/unit_converter/numbers.html

Comment: You need to parse hex and then format in base32. Search for other questions around this - there are *loads* of questions about parsing hex to a byte array, and there are libraries for base32 formatting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can do it this way:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("000000000288", 16);
String base32 = Integer.toString(number, 32);
```

**Edit: Sorry, I forgot to add the radix parameter to the first line. I have changed it now.**

Comment: When converting to int, always be aware of possible loss of precision. It may be a better idea to use Long instead of Integer.

Answer (score 1):

I find java's [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to be the best among them all for **bit manipulation**. Among its wide usages (mainly with **storing huge numbers**, upto your memory stack can allow and for its wide array of supported operations), you do have the option for **base conversion from 2 to 36**.

*Example Code :*

```
BigInteger num=new BigInteger("000000000288",16);     //Store as Hexa

//Display the result using BigInteger.toString(radix)
System.out.println("Result = "+num.toString(32));    //Showing result in 32 base
```

Ofcourse if you are dealing with numbers having **Fractional part**, you will have to use Magicode's method of `Integer.toString(radix)`. Or if your number is bigger than what `int` can store, I suggest you run your own function for Base Conversion for the fraction part.